# Reading a mix of integers and characters from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, getline, token

I have some trouble with reading of a file in C++. I am able to read only integers or only alphabets. But I am not able to read both for example, 10af, ff5a. My procedure is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

if (argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "You should provide a file name." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

std::ifstream input_file(argv[1]);
if (!input_file) {
    std::cerr << "I can't read " << argv[1] << "." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

std::string line;
for (int line_no = 1; std::getline(input_file, line); ++line_no) {
    //std::cout << line << std::endl;

         -----------
    }
       return 0;
 }
```

So what I am trying to do is, I am allowing the user to specify the input file he wants to read, and I am using getline to obtain each line. I can use the method of tokens to read only integers or only alphabets. But I am not able to read a mix of both. If my input file is

2 1 89ab

8 2 16ff

What is the best way to read this file?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by method of tokens. Are you trying to tokenize each line and it fails? then why don't you include that part of the code here?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/), and use [`std::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/) since 89ab and 16ff look like hex numbers.

Should look like this:

```
std::string line;
for (int line_no = 1; std::getline(input_file, line); ++line_no)
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    int a, b, c;

    ss >> a;
    ss >> b;
    ss >> std::hex >> c;
 }
```

You will need to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: Ya you are right. This makes sense to me. It works fine. I have understood now what to do. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
std::string s;
while (input_file >> s) {
  //add s to an array or process s
  ...
}
```

you can read inputs of type `std::string` which could be any combination of digits and alphabets. You don't necessarily need to read input line by line and then try to parse it. `>>` operator considers both space and newline as delimiters.

Comment: Oh Ok. Thanks. I will try that out. I didnt know I could do this.